# Selecting 2 pole branch circuit protection

Tags: transformer, protection, circuit-protection

I am trying to select a 2 pole circuit protector (UL489 approved), to protect a 575V transformer. I am however unable to find any 2 pole CB that go above a 480Vac voltage rating. Is there anything I'm missing when it comes to branch circuit protection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is easier to search directly for 600V equipment. Here is a list of some found through Google:

Siemens Industry ED62B030

Altech AB series

Comment: Note: I'm not entirely sure that I understand your problem. I guess this is a three phase system which is outside of my "comfort zone".

Comment: I should have mentioned this in my question but I'm looking for 2 pole Circuit breakers. Thank you for the answer